# Fluent API - One to many - multiple relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, entity, fluent

Hello I have a following problem that I am trying to resolve using Fluent API.

I have 2 tables:

**Product:**  ID int   | Code nvarchar(20)  | CurrentDetailsID int

**ProductDetails** ID int | ProductID int | Name navrachar(50) ....

Now my relations are a bit strange because:
Product can contain only one current product details (CurrentDetailsID), each details record cand be linked only to one product, but product itself can contain multiple Details as well (for historic reasons).

Any idea how I can archive such tricky type of relations in fluent API?

Seb

Comment: Is it possible to add an IsCurrent bit field to the ProductDetails table and remove the CurrentDetailsID altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Define your classes as following:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int CurrentProductDetailId { get; set; } 
    public virtual ProductDetail CurrentProductDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
}
public class ProductDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

If you want use Fluent API you can use following code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
               .HasMany(t => t.ProductDetails)
               .WithRequired(t=>t.Product)
               .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProductId);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
               .HasRequired(t => t.CurrentProductDetail)
               .WithRequiredPrincipal()
               .Map(m => m.MapKey("CurrentProductDetailId"));
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: But how to archive that using fluent API?

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work. I do have an error saying that multiplicity is not allowed :'(